# Page generation to fit list overflow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have built a classifieds web project (ASP.NET MVC) where uploaded items are displayed in thumbnails everything works fine however I only want 12 items to show on each page. After adding the database items to a list I then used

```
List<Bike> BikesList = Bikes.GetAll()
.OrderByDescending(b => b.Ad.PostingTime)
.Take(12)
.ToList();
```

The items display fine but what I need to figure out is how to code auto page generation for displaying the other items in the list. As this is to be deployed in a real world scenario the list will be both growing and diminishing so I need functionality to deal with this, I assume this task will happen at run time so will only create pages required for the current list items.

Any help would be great as I am completely stumped with this one. Here is the code I have which make the thumbnails for display.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "BikeAds", new { id = item.ID })">
                            <img title="@item.Title" src="~/images/@item.Images.First().Path" alt="@item.Title">
                        </a>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4 title="@item.Title">
                                @Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", new { id = item.ID })
                            </h4>
                            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VehicleBrand.Name), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year.YearNo), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DrivenKilometers) KMs Driven, @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Color.Name), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Condition.ConditionType) Condition. @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ratings">
                            <p title="@item.Currency.Name : @item.Price" class="pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Currency.ISOCode) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</p>
                            <p title="@item.City.Name, @item.State.Name, @item.Country.Name">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i>&nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City.Name)
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

Forgive me if this question is not worded correctly or missing details which would aid answering please remember this is my first time to use this forum and I am not long coding in MVC (Or anything for that matter).

Comment: Consider using [PagedList](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList)

Comment: Thanks Stephen Muecke I will try this hopefully this sorts out this problem, I assume this will no affect the output if the user bookmarks whatever page they are viewing am I right? One more thing I am unsure how to mark your reply as solved or do I do that after I implement the solution.

Comment: I back at this again, I tried pagedList and had some success but everything I found online to help mainly evolved around displaying lists/tables.When I tried to apply the same to the thumbnails everything fell apart. I had everything wired up to use IEnumerable Model so when I then tried to change this to the IPagedList the errors. Everything relies on IEnumerable action links in the thumbnails ect. Put simply I need pagination but that deals with thumbnails and a way to implement this where I have everything wired up to deal with IEnumerable lists. Links dealing with this would be awesome.